# Changing Android process's nice values

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, cgroups, nice

I understand that changing the nice value of any app can be done using the terminal with the "renice" function. My code to renice: `renice -n <increment> <pid>`

However, it seems like the new nice value only stays for foreground applications. Once I leave the app by pressing the home button, if i go back to that app, the nice value resumes. Is there a reason for this? As such I always force the renice function on the current foreground app. If this is the case, is it possible to change the nice values of background apps?

P.S For some applications, the OS seems to constantly change the nice value by itself, for instance, foreground apps usually have a nice value of -10. But for some apps, this value may change during runtime even if it is still the current foreground app. Not sure why this happens?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this?  Its very rarely a good idea or necessary, even on a normal computer.

Comment: @GabeSechan it is for a school research project, you have any clue why all those things mentioned happens?